# line integral problem, stuck in the curve

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Problem:
A force field is given in polar coordinates by the equation
$$F(r,\theta)= (-4\sin (\theta), 4\sin (\theta)).$$

Compute the work done in moving a particle from the point $(1,0)$ to the origin along the spiral whose polar equation is $r = e^{-\theta}$.

my Try:

what I think is to take $\alpha(t)=(e^{-t},t)$ $ ( \alpha'(t)=(-e^{-t},1))$ to describe the curve but $0 \leq t \leq +\infty$ beacuse $\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty} e^{-t}=0$ and that's the origin.

then $\int^{+\infty}_{0} F(\alpha(t))\cdot \alpha'(t) \,dt=\int^{+\infty}_{0} \sin(t)e^{-t}+\sin(t)\, dt$ and the last doesn't converge. I think my problem is do not parameterize the curve in a good way.

Comment: What is a "force field given in polar coordinates"? Force fields live in the $(x,y)$-plane (or in $(x,y,z)$-space), and not in an abstract $(r,\theta)$-plane.

Comment: So I should get $G(x,y)$ using $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ and $\alpha(t)=(e^{-t}\cos(t),e^{-t}\sin(t))$. in that case the domain of $\alpha$ is ? $t\in [0,??]$ or I'm thinking wrong again... thanks for answer

Comment: Go back to your source! I don't know how to interpret $(-4\sin\theta,4\sin\theta)$.

Comment: polar coordinates are $(x,y)=(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$ and $F$ is given in polar coordinates, from  $(x,y)=(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$ I get $\theta (x,y)= \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) $ then $F(r,\theta)=(-4\sin(\arctan(\frac{y}{x})), 4\sin(\arctan(\frac{y}{x})))=G(x,y)$ where $G$ is a force field in $xy$. I could solve it, thanks for your observation.